# Should Cache be re-built when changing list.phtml

Tags: magento-1.9

I need to modify catalog listing and Product pages. Should Cache be re-built when changing/modifying list.phtml, or Price.phtml?

Comment: By coding, what have you tried?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I need to implement http://blog.yanted.com/2014/07/10/price-range-of-configurable-products-in-magento/ on product listing and production description page. Need to display the lowest and the highest product with attribute price on the listing and the product description pages.